# What is the top of a pearl pendant called?

Tags: expressions, diction

For example the top of the pendant in the link below:

[top of a pearl pendant](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B1MKZ1K)

Comment: Why did you include the word _pearl_ in the title of your question? Do you think this would have a different name if the pendant was, say, a ruby pendant?

Comment: The OP was a friend of mine and we were looking exclusively at pearls at the time. Apologies for any confusion.

Answer (score 5):

Pendant itself is the word you are looking for,

[Macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/pendant) has the following definition of pendant.

> Pendant > a piece of jewelry that hangs from a chain around your neck

<sub>Note: Gems and other precious stones are the ones which get set in the top of the pendant or rings. And they are just know by their names, like oh what a diamond ring, or a beautiful sapphire necklace.</sub>

[image: Here is what i got when googled for the pendant]

---

Other related terms not to be confused with are :

[Bail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bail_%28jewelry%29) > a component of certain types of jewelry, mostly necklaces, that is used to attach a pendant or stone.,

[image]

[Setting](http://www.asia-gems.com/jewelry/settings-type-function.php) > what holds an individual gem,

[image]

[Mounting](http://www.asia-gems.com/jewelry/settings-type-function.php) > includes the collection of settings and connects to the shank of a ring or other jewelry

Comment: @J.R., added pics to clarify what i was saying.

Comment: I don't think the bail is the hook per se, it depends on the type of bail used. There are donut bails, pinch bails, glue-on bails, wire wrapped bails, etc. You can find more information [here](http://www.wire-to-jewelry.com/jewelry-bails.html), see more than 80 bails for sale [here](http://www.silverenchantments.com/Jewelry-Findings-Components_a.html), or watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9XeM0Ie7m0) to see that not all bails have hooks.

Comment: @J.R., 
The first [link](http://www.wire-to-jewelry.com/jewelry-bails.html) you suggest is giving this information/what should we infer from it??
> A jewelry bail is a jewelry making component (findings) that attaches a pendant to a necklace, chain, cord etc.
> And also, if we go through all the images in the second [link](http://www.silverenchantments.com/Jewelry-Findings-Components_a.html) provided by you, same is the result, something to hold or latch from.

Comment: Raghav, here is what you said in your answer: "Bail > the hook." Here is what you said in your comment to Matthew: "**it is the hook**" [emphasis in the original]. Here is what you said in a comment to me: "i meant bail is actually the hook." Now, here is my point: _Not all bails have hooks._

Comment: @J.R., oh sorry for not being clear,and going to remove that comment, plus edit wherever was not clear enough, all i wanted was to give a quick idea but i also remember everywhere i used a reference from where i was mentioning[and in Matthew's answer the complete definition was from the source he mentioned]. Got your point though.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's called a *bail*.

**Reference**: [Wikipedia entry for bail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bail_%28jewelry%29).

Answer (score 2):

*Bail* is probably the correct technical term, but if you wanted to buy such an item (for crafting), the word you want is ***setting*** or ***mounting***.

You can see some examples at [this website](http://www.firemountaingems.com/mountings.asp?navsrc=2).